# Have a sub query typpe search in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

In my current ELK I am getting logs where if a user fails login I get "User X Failed" and when a user logins successfully I get "User X Successful". X gets stored in a separate tag too (logged_user). I want to find out in a given time period that who are the users who have failed login but don't have a success log associated with them
e.g: User A and User B failed login but then User B logged in successfully. So I should only see User x been reported in my query result.

Is there a way to do the same via ELK/Kibana so that I can make a visualization of the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are no join in elasticsearch , so you cannot join an index with itself and compare values. Your requirement should be either be resolved using scripted metric aggregation or better should be done at client side(getting all the records in that range and filtering it).

I am using [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) to create a dictionary of unique feedbackIdentifierI and feedback value.

1. "init_script":

> Executed prior to any collection of documents. Allows the aggregation
>   to set up any initial state.

Have declared a hashtable transactions"

2. "map_script"

> Executed once per document collected
>   Loop through all document and add unique logged_user and corresponding timestamp and message value to dictionary. I am getting last entry of that user in given time range

3. combine_script

> Executed once on each shard after document collection is complete

Return dictionary for all shards

4. reduce_script

> Executed once on the coordinating node after all shards have returned their results

Once again go through through all dictionary returned from each shard and create a single unique dictionary .

**Data:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index31",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4W2uC3IBFQk2sliOGJWu",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timestamp" : "2020-05-13",
          "logged_user" : "Abc",
          "message" : "User Abc logged successful"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index31",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4m2uC3IBFQk2sliOj5Wg",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timestamp" : "2020-05-12",
          "logged_user" : "Xyz",
          "message" : "User Xyz loggin failed"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index31",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "422uC3IBFQk2sliOt5US",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timestamp" : "2020-05-13",
          "logged_user" : "Xyz",
          "message" : "User Xyz loggin successful"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index31",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5G3CC3IBFQk2sliO9ZW0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timestamp" : "2020-05-12",
          "logged_user" : "Abc",
          "message" : "User Abc loggin failed"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Query:**

```
GET index31/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2020-05-12",
        "lte": "2020-05-13"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "login_failed": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.transactions =new Hashtable();",
        "map_script": """ def message="";
                          if(doc['message.keyword'].value.indexOf('failed')>-1)
                          {
                            message="failed"; 
                          }else{
                            message="successful"; 
                          }
                          if(state.transactions.get(doc['logged_user.keyword'])==null)
                          {
                            state.transactions.put(doc['logged_user.keyword'].value,[ doc.timestamp,message])
                          }else{
                              def user= state.transactions.get(doc['logged_user.keyword'].value);
                              if(user[0]<doc.timestamp)
                              {
                                user[0]= doc.timestamp;
                                user[1]=message;
                              }
                          }
                         """,
        "combine_script": "return state.transactions",
        "reduce_script": """
                            def loggins=new Hashtable();
                            for(a in states){
                                for(entry in a.entrySet()){
                                  if(loggins.get(entry.getKey())==null){
                                    loggins.put(entry.getKey(),[entry.getValue()[0],entry.getValue()[1]]);
                                  }else{
                                     def user= loggins.get(entry.getKey());
                                     if(user[0]<entry.getValue())
                                     {
                                        user[0]= entry.getValue()[0];
                                        user[1]= entry.getValue()[1];
                                     }
                                  }
                                }
                            }

                            def failed_loggins=new Hashtable();
                            for(entry in loggins.entrySet()){
                              if(entry.getValue()[1] =='failed')
                              {
                                 failed_loggins.put(entry.getKey(),[entry.getValue()[0],entry.getValue()[1]]);
                              }
                            }
                            return failed_loggins;"""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Scripted_metric aggregation is not supported in Kabana visualization so above will not work if you trying to visualize in kibana(only dev tools will support it)

**Result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "login_failed" : {
      "value" : {
        "Abc" : [
          [
            "2020-05-12T00:00:00.000Z"
          ],
          "failed"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```